# Unable to return observalble value from subscribtion

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have been trying to return "students" from my function as an observable, in my code, I am using functions from another service, and these functions return an observable to which I am subscribing. From "classRoom" I am separating students and passing them to another function that returns an array which is then stored in "students".

In the console.log "Log-1" I get the desired output but if I try to return that as an observable or console.log it in "Log-2" it is undefined.

```
public GetActiveStudents(): Observable<IStudent[]> {
    this.dashboardService.getData().subscribe((res) => {
      this.dashboardService.getDashboardSchools().subscribe((schools) => {
        this.schools = schools;
        this.start = new Date();
        this.end = new Date();
        this.start.setMonth(this.start.getMonth() - 1);

        schools.forEach((schools) => {
          this.classRooms = this.classRooms.concat(schools.classRooms);
        });

        this.classRooms.forEach((classRoom) => {
          this.students = this.dashboardService.numActiveTwo(this.students.concat(classRoom.students), 'students', this.start, this.end);
        });
        console.log("Log-1" + this.students);
      });
    });
    console.log("Log-2" + this.students);
    
    return of(this.students)
  }
```

Comment: subscribe is an asynchronous call which means that this will run when the data is returned  not when called so your `Log-2` outside the subscribe function is actually performed before the code in the subscribe bc the calls returns later. In the console the `Log-2` will be before `Log-1`.

Comment: you should return of(this.students) inside the   this.dashboardService.getDashboardSchools()

Comment: `getData().subscribe((res) => {// do stuff})` means the following: "Whenever `getData` returns something do stuff using the result returned". **Whenever** here is the key word. If `getData` is synchronous, then "do stuff" will happen synchronously, i.e. before  "Log-2" gets printed. If `getData` is asynchronous, it will happen later, in some of the next loops of the Javascript engine, hence it will happen after "Log-2". If you use rxjs, you want to go for a reactive style, which means to write code that says "when this thing occurs, do stuff" rather then imperative, which is "just do stuff".

Answer (score 2):

Mixing Observables with setting class variables is always a recipe for chaos.
But lets try to get it do what you want :P.

```
GetActiveStudents(): Observable<IStudent[]> {
  return this.dashboardService.getData().pipe(
    mergeMap((res) => {
      return this.dashboardService.getDashboardSchools().pipe(mergeMap((schools) => {
        this.schools = schools;
        this.start = new Date();
        this.end = new Date();
        this.start.setMonth(this.start.getMonth() - 1);

        schools.forEach((schools) => {
          this.classRooms = this.classRooms.concat(schools.classRooms);
        });

        this.classRooms.forEach((classRoom) => {
          this.students = this.dashboardService.numActiveTwo(this.students.concat(classRoom.students), 'students', this.start, this.end);
        });
        return of(this.students);
      }));
    })
  );
}
```

What did we do? In general, we used mergeMap to get to the next Observable and return it upwards, the returned observable does nothing till it gets subscribed somewhere in the code.

I encourage you to overthink the structure of your code, it won't be maintainable in the future. Try it, maybe in a more declarative way and try to not overwrite class properties to reduce side effects.
(for example, is it really necessary to do this.start = new Date() ? )

Comment: Agree! @ScriptType, This was not a good approach. I removed "this.start = new Date()" and "this.end = new Date()", those were not necessary, also moved the subscription to ngOnInit where I wanted to get the value, it works now without requiring me to return anything. Thank you so much for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

Your Log-2 is outside of the subscription, and therefor gets hit before the getDashboardSchools() emits returns a value. You are also setting the component variable (this.students) in the function, while returning the same value as an observable response.

I would suggest you declare and populate a variable in the function, and return it as an observable:

```
public GetActiveStudents(): Observable<IStudent[]> {
    this.dashboardService.getData().subscribe((res) => {
      this.dashboardService.getDashboardSchools().subscribe((schools) => {
        this.schools = schools;
        this.start = new Date();
        this.end = new Date();
        this.start.setMonth(this.start.getMonth() - 1);
        let students: IStudents[] = [];
        schools.forEach((schools) => {
          this.classRooms = this.classRooms.concat(schools.classRooms);
        });

        this.classRooms.forEach((classRoom) => {
          students = this.dashboardService.numActiveTwo(this.students.concat(classRoom.students), 'students', this.start, this.end);
        });

      });
    });
    
    return of(students);
  }
```

Then, subscribe your function in the ngOnInit (or where ever you need it), and set the component variable (this.students) with the value emitted by your observable function:

```
ngOnInit()
{
    this.GetActiveStudents().subscribe(res => {
        this.students = res;
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can actually return something from a subscribe method?

Answer (score 1):

First of all Subscribe work as asynchronous. The console.log "Log-1" you are getting the desired output because this is written inside subscribe and the function must return value from subscribe so Log-1 contains desired output but console.log "Log-2" is written outside of subscribe, this code does not wait to complete subscribe method and execute suddenly just after subscribe so value of Log-2 is undefined.